# How to block zoom mode for our app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, swift5

I want to ignore the zoom mode accessibility for my app. So far i haven’t found any solutions through which i can handle this.
Or should I say how to handle zoom mode for our app.

Comment: I don't think so there is a way to handle zoom mode, as it is a system functionality irrespective of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is a way to handle zoom mode, as it is a system functionality irrespective of the applications. correct me if I am wrong.